# how to disable button on particular date in angular?

Tags: angular, typescript

Below is a java-script which works fine to disable a button on particular date, how to do the same in angular.?

```
var serverdate = new Date();
var dd= serverdate.getDate();
var mm= serverdate.getMonth()+1;
var year = serverdate.getFullYear();
var day=serverdate.getDay();
var hours = serverdate.getHours();
var minute = serverdate.getMinutes();

if(mm==1 && dd==18)
{
  console.log('Achieve you want')
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What you want is not clear. You can achieve your requirement with the above code in angular. Then whats the problem?

Comment: nope you cannot, refer below 'Talavera' answer @AshrafulIslam

Comment: Is Talavera's answer worked for you?

Comment: yes i have marked as correct @AshrafulIslam

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your component:

```
date = new Date(); // no let because you are in the component scope, let only when the scope is different
```

In your HTML:

```
<button class="btn" [disabled]="date.getMonth()+1 && date.getDate() === 18">Date</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

so here is a simple example,

define a boolean variable in ts file

```
buttonDisable : boolean : false;
 serverdate : Date;
```

after your logic

```
 this.serverdate = new Date();
var dd= this.serverdate.getDate();
var mm= this.serverdate.getMonth()+1;
var year = this.serverdate.getFullYear();
var day= this.serverdate.getDay();
var hours = this.serverdate.getHours();
var minute = this.serverdate.getMinutes();

if(mm==1 && dd==18)
{
  this.buttonDisable = true;
  console.log('Achieve you want')
}
```

in HTML file

```
<button [disabled]="buttonDisable"> 
</button>
```

hope this helps.

Comment: what not works, the button is not disabled or the logic?

Comment: logic, i cannot able to declare "let serverdate = new Date();" in .ts

Comment: let typescript know your serverdate is Date object by assigning it to Date. please check my updated answer.